How to implement a scroll Parallax effect in the React project
I've implemented this effect custom React Hook without using any other module.
I added a hook code and an example.
// Hook
export const useScroll = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef<any>(null);
  const checkVisible = () => {
    const offset = ((element) => {
      let offset = 0;
      while (element) {
        offset += element.offsetTop;
        element = element.offsetParent;
      }
      return offset;
    })(ref.current);
    const scrollY = window.scrollY;
    if (offset - scrollY > (window.innerHeight * 3) / 4) return false;
    else return true;
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    setVisible(checkVisible());
    const scrollHandler = (_: Event) => {
      setVisible(checkVisible());
    };
    window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);
    };
  }, []);
  return { visible, element: ref };
};

// Example
export const Item = () => {
  const { visible, element } = useScroll();
  return (
    <Div
      visibility={visible ? "visible" : "hidden"}
      opacity={visible ? "1" : "0"}
      transition={"500ms"}
      transform={
        visible ? "scale(1) translateY(0%)" : "scale(0.8) translateY(100%)"
      }
      ref={element}
    >
    ...

Please share if there's any better way to implement it so easily.
My solution has some problems when the items are so many.
If you have a better way to easily implement this, please share.
My solution has some problems if there are too many items, because it add so many event listeners.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
